# C# string.Split returns double quotes out of no where

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why does this

```
        string test = "Text1, Text2";
        string [] tests = test.Split(", ".ToArray());
```

returns this

```
[0] = "Text1"
[1] = ""
[2] = "Text2"
```

what's with the quotes in tests[1] ?

I thought the output would be like this

```
[0] = "Text1"
[1] = "Text2"
```

Comment: Why you added .ToArray() to ", " ?

Comment: What's with the quotes in tests[1]? All three values have quotes. It's just that tests[1] has nothing else because it's empty. Use StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries to remove empty values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a **LINQ extension method** that is causing you grief!

You'll find that `System.String` implements `IEnumerable<char>` which allows strings to use any of the LINQ extension methods - and you are calling `TSource[] ToArray<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)`. So instead of splitting on an array of strings, you are splitting on an array of characters.

Your code can be rewritten as:

```
string test = "Text1, Text2";
char[] separator = ", ".ToArray();
string[] tests = test.Split(separator);
```

Since your input contains two of the separator characters next to each other you get the empty string in your output array.

There isn't a `Split` method on `System.String` that takes a single string as the separator. Instead you must pass in an array of string separators. The method also requires that you provide the `StringSplitOptions` parameter.

So this is what you need to call:

```
string test = "Text1, Text2";
string[] separator = new [] { ", " };
string[] tests = test.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Thanks for the complete explanation and answer

Answer (score 1):

```
string [] tests = test.Split(new string[] { ", " });
```

What about this?

`String.ToArray()` splits the string into the chars array, but you need an array of strings as an argument of `String.Split()`.

Comment: That would work iff you added this StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries to the Split method parameter as the only overload that accepts a string array, also takes StringSplitOptions object.

Answer (score 1):

`", ".ToArray()` results an character array like:

```
{ ',', ' '}  //a ',' and a space
```

so there are **TWO** separators (matches the `string.Split(params char[])` version).

You should do it like this:

```
string test = "Text1, Text2";
string[] tests = test.Split(new string[] { ", " }, 
                             StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
// Updated
```

or

```
string test = "Text1, Text2";
string[] tests = test.Split(',');
// or: string[] tests = test.Split(new char[]{ ',' });
```

Comment: +1 for the simple explanation, but please edit your answer because the first solution will give a compilation error as string.Split won't accept a string as a parameter but if you placed the ", " in a string array it will work.....and the second solution is working but it will result in unnecessary space as the separator is ", " not ','  Thanks for the help =)

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
string test = "Text1, Text2";
string [] tests = test.Split(", ".ToArray());
```

equals to

```
string test = "Text1, Text2";
string [] tests = test.Split(new char[2]{',',' '});
```

You should use

```
string test = "Text1, Text2";
string [] tests = test.Split(',');
```

Comment: In this case the second `tests` item will have unnecessary space in the begin.

Comment: @zerkms +1 that's right, and I'll use this output in a search method so it can't have any unnecessary characters.

Comment: That is not a problem that author of quesstion tried to resolve. My solution resolves author's issue with empty string in Array. It is possible use ", " instead of ',' to not have space character.

Answer (score 0):

Change ToArray() to ToCharArray().